# iOS architectures vs Valid Architectures and repercussions of settings

Tags: ios

I have a library that is not 64 bit ready, so I removed arm64 from "architectures". I was then able to use the application on 64 bit platforms in the simulator. (It didn't work until I made that change. It would just crash)

When I was going to create an archive for my app to send to the store, I got the following error:

```
(null): File is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/cmuench/Desktop/PHP-Point-Of-Sale-Repos/PHP-Point-Of-Sale-iOS/PHP Point Of Sale/starSDK/StarIO.framework/StarIO file '/Users/cmuench/Desktop/PHP-Point-Of-Sale-Repos/PHP-Point-Of-Sale-iOS/PHP Point Of Sale/starSDK/StarIO.framework/StarIO' for architecture armv7s
```

I think this is because the another framework I use I am using for a receipt printer doesn't support `armv7s`.

3 questions:

1. Why was it able to work in debugging environment but then fail when creating an archive? The only way I could get the archive to work was by removing `armv7s` from "valid architectures"
2. Will my application work on newer hardware that uses the armv7s platform? (I don't have the newer hardware)
3. What is the difference between "architectures" and "Valid Architectures" in build settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the simulator, the architecture is i386 not armv7 or armv7s. You would only get this error if you tried to run a debug session in a iOS device which had an armv7s chip.
2. Yes, arm64 and armv7s will run armv7 binaries.
3. [Build Setting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) describes all the build settings.

   - **ARCHS (Architectures)**: Space-separated list of identifiers. Specifies the architectures (ABIs, processor models) to which the binary is targeted. When this build setting specifies more than one architecture, the generated binary may contain object code for each of the specified architectures.
   - **VALID_ARCHS (Valid Architectures)**: Space-separated list of identifiers. Specifies the architectures for which the binary may be built. During the build, this list is intersected with the value of ARCHS build setting; the resulting list specifies the architectures the binary can run on. If the resulting architecture list is empty, the target generates no binary.